# Python - reading Oracle from Linux or Windows with the SAME code

Tags: python, oracle, client

here is a background: We have an Oracle server running on Windows. Years ago I wrote a client (windows) which reads data from Oracle, process, create XML and send it back to the instrument (mass spectrometer) controlling software (running on the same machine as Oracle). Utility was written in C++ as dll with two wrappers: GUI and console (for LIMS). Connection has been done via ADO/ODBC, so you don't have to have Oracle client installed (MS for Oracle ODBC driver works just fine...) Works like a charm for years, but... Now LIMS is migrating to Linux. I have a choice to make:

1. to write a Linux version and maintain both Win and Linux (which is NOT good), or
2. to write platform independent code (thinking of Python) and live happily ever after.

here is my (poorly formulated) question: **Is it possible to write Python code which reads Oracle data residing on either Linux or Windows PROVIDING no Oracle client installed?**

**Edit**:reformulating poorly formulated question: **What are minimal changes I have to make for standard Python configuration/lib in order to use the same code on either Linux or Windows for reading Oracle data?**

All I need just to execute a bunch of SELECT statements, READ ONLY.

already done:

1. understand that it CAN be done in Java
2. Python: I can detect what platform I am running on and branch the code if necessary (I'll do that, but prefer NOT to, may be just a connect string?)
3. looked at Python cx_Oracle, still can't understand if I can use it and have the same code for Linux and Win (writing test right now)

Any inside will be much appreciated. Thanks

**Edit1:** found a very good starting point: thanks to  [cx_Oracle and the data source paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1148472/753117)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pyodbc might be another option:

http://pyodbc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I've already got pyodbc and cx_Oracle and will know soon enough what mess I am getting myself in..

Answer (score 0):

Your question

> Is it possible to write Python code
>   which reads Oracle data residing on
>   either

does not make much sense this you can access *any* database in a portable way
by using the standard Python DB API which is implemented by all related database bindings.

So what is the specific problem here?

In every case you need platform and specific bindings on your system in order to let your underlaying Python database driver talk to Oracle or which ever database but this is completely independent of any application code. In theory the code could work against every database as long as there is a driver and as long as your application uses "standard" SQL features.

Comment: @Sentinel Yea, I've poorly formulated my question. Though you missed *"PROVIDING no Oracle client installed?"*. What I am trying to say: "Within standard Python configuration, with minimal changes to a system..." I'll try to reformulate it

Comment: You need a ODBC driver or native Oracle driver in every case.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I am trying to figure out why, for example, the same connect string will open db on Win, but not on Linux. It might be something trivial like slash backslash, or something deeper

Comment: My point is a footprint.  Oracle client is 200-400 MB. I know for sure that if I have Ora client installed I can run practically the same code on Linux and Win (with some twiks). Will it be the same with system provided drivers?

Comment: as said: you need odbc or native drivers - what is your further point?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: I don't have to install anything new, just call a system ODBC provider (configured) using the same connect string for Linux or Win?

Comment: import odbc   
s = odbc.odbc('DSN/UID/PASSWORD')   
cur = s.cursor()   
cur.execute('select * from table1')

Comment: Ok, I guess you are right giving general answer on my very general question. Blame on me... But I can still dream of an answer like "You should download odbcxxx.py from odbc.sourceforge.net and you are all set", can I?

Comment: @Nikiton: This is sidestepping your original question, but if the size of the Oracle client is you biggest concern, it might be worth taking a look at the Instant Client.  There are versions that don't include SQL*Plus or any of the other tools, which brings the size down to under 50 MB.